# How to force wait() to completely wait for subprocess.Popen() to complete

Tags: python, subprocess, wait, popen

I'm trying to transfer and rename some files in a while loop using the subprocess.Popen(['cp', etc..]) and wait(). Unfortunately it appears that wait() command is not properly working, i.e. not waiting for the file to completely copy to the new directory. Most of the time the files copy over fine, however, a small subset of random files do not (not the same files each time I run the script) and are thus zero byte files or incomplete files. I have also tried using subprocess.check_call() but this does not work either. When I print the poll() value it's always zero which should mean the process has finished. Note all files I'm dealing with are in the range of 150KBs. My python script is being run in pyraf utilising python 2.7, python version of iraf (image reduction and analysis facility) since I'm using iraf routines. Is there any way to force Popen() or check_call() to wait for the file transfer to complete?

```
while count <= ncross_correlate and skip_flag != 's':
   ...more stuff
   try:
      iraf.rv.fxcor (object_fits, template_fits, apertures="*", cursor="",
      continuum="both", filter="both", rebin="smallest", pixcorr="no", 
      osample=osample_reg, rsample=osample_reg, apodize=0.1, function="gaussian",
      width="INDEF", height=0., peak="no", minwidth=3., maxwidth=21., weights=1.,
      background=0., window=300., wincenter="INDEF", output=output_name, verbose="long",
      imupdate="no", graphics="stdgraph", interactive="no", autowrite="yes",
      autodraw="yes", ccftype="image", observatory="aao", continpars="", filtpars="", 
      keywpars="")

      # Create a eps file of the cross_correlation file.
      gki_output_name = output_name + '.gki'
      iraf.plot.sgikern (gki_output_name, device='eps', generic='no', debug='no',
      verbose='no', gkiunit='no')
```

Unfortunately the only way to convert the .gki file created in fxcor to some readable
format outside of iraf is to call the iraf task sgikern which dumps an .eps file in my
iraf/iraf/ directory without giving the option to change the file name or directory placement. In fact the filename is randomly generated. Very frustrating!!! Also note that nothing is wrong with any of the eps files created using iraf.plot.sgikern (i.e. no 0 KB files to begin with). Copying and renaming is where I have issues.

```
      # Find the eps file in /iraf/iraf/, rename it, and move to proper output location.
      iraf_dir = '/iraf/iraf/'
      eps_file_list = glob.glob(iraf_dir + 'sgi' + '*.eps')

      ...more code
```

At this point I have tried using check_call() or Popen():

```
      subprocess.check_call(['cp', eps_file_list[0], ccf_output_dir + object_name_sub +
                            '.eps'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      subprocess.check_call(['rm', eps_file_list[0]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or

```
      process1 = subprocess.Popen(['cp', eps_file_list[0], ccf_output_dir +
                                  object_name_sub + '.eps'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      process1.wait()
      process2 = subprocess.Popen(['rm', eps_file_list[0]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      process2.wait()

      ...more stuff

   # end of try statement
#end of while statement
```

I reckon if I could somehow combine the two Popen statement in to a single Popen statement and also include a shell sleep time of maybe 0.01s to force the other two processes to finish before returning a completed process, that would probably fix it. Maybe something like this, though I'm not sure of the exact sentax:

```
 process1 = subprocess.Popen(['cp', eps_file_list[0], ccf_output_dir +
            object_name_sub + '.eps']; ['rm', eps_file_list[0]]; ['sleep', 0.01],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 process1.wait()
```

Hopefully this gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do. I've been trying lots of different things and looking all over for a solution to this problem and I'm truly stuck.

Cheers,
Brett

Comment: there is function called `communicate`, will help you

Comment: Irrelevant, but that `fxcor` function signature is ridiculous.

Comment: I don't see how communicate will help me. Can you please give an example Grijesh. Fxcor does have a lot of inputs, hence why the calling sequence is long. Basically fxcor stands for Fourier cross-correlation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following would be sufficient:

```
subprocess.check_call(['mv', eps_file_list[0], ccf_output_dir + object_name_sub +
                        '.eps'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and

```
process1 = subprocess.Popen(['mv', eps_file_list[0], ccf_output_dir +
                              object_name_sub + '.eps'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process1.wait()
```

Comment: I don't think having two move processes would work. If the file has been partially moved by the first command before the second one is called than the second command most likely won't find the file to move (since it's already being moved by the first command). Am I right?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to actually use both together,  I was suggesting to use the one style or the other, as suggested in your example.

Comment: Essentially,  why not use 'mv' instead of 'cp' and then 'rm'.

Comment: I tried using 'mv' but still had the same problem. I actually I was originally using 'mv' before someone suggested 'cp' and then 'rm'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [shutil.copyfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) for the copy and [os.remove](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) for the deletion?

If you really want to use Subprocess, I believe the syntax is something like this:

```
process1 = subprocess.Popen('cp ' + eps_file_list[0] + ' ' + ccf_output_dir +
        object_name_sub + '.eps; rm ' + eps_file_list[0] ' + '; sleep 0.01',
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This way, the command you're calling is all in one string: `'cp whatever foo/bar.eps; rm whatever; sleep 0.01'`

You can also format the string with triple quotes and have the commands on separate lines:

```
'''
cp %s %s%s
rm %s
sleep %s
''' % (eps_file_list[0], ccf_output_dir, object_name_sub, eps_file_list[0], 0.01)
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, yes I have considered shutil.copyfile and os.remove, however, I run into the same issues. I did figure out how to combine multiple Popen commands by doing this: cmd1 = 'cp {0} {1}'.format(iraf_dir + eps_file, ccf_output_dir + object_name_sub + '.eps')
                  cmd2 = 'rm {0}'.format(iraf_dir + eps_file)
                  cmd3 = 'sleep 0.05'
                  process1 = subprocess.Popen("{}; {}; {}".format(cmd1, cmd2, cmd3), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                  process1.wait()

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete solution nor a satisfying one but it's the best I have come up with and works ~99.9% of the time (out of 4000+ eps I create, 5 files were I either 0 byte or incomplete). This is an improvement over the original way I was doing this which was successful about 95% of the time. I have pasted the code below:

```
     try:
        iraf.rv.fxcor (object_fits, template_fits, apertures="*", cursor="",
        continuum="both", filter="both", rebin="smallest", pixcorr="no", osample=osample_reg,
        rsample=osample_reg, apodize=0.1, function="gaussian", width="INDEF", height=0., peak="no",
        minwidth=3., maxwidth=21., weights=1., background=0., window=300.,
        wincenter="INDEF", output=output_name, verbose="long", imupdate="no",
        graphics="stdgraph", interactive="no", autowrite="yes", autodraw="yes",
        ccftype="image", observatory="aao", continpars="", filtpars="", keywpars="")

        # Create a eps file of the cross_correlation file.
        gki_output_name = output_name + '.gki'
        iraf.plot.sgikern (gki_output_name, device='eps', generic='no', debug='no',
        verbose='no', gkiunit='no')
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

I put a time sleeper here as I discovered that some of the ps files being created in my iraf directory had not been fully written by the time the my code tried to move the file to another directory.

```
        # Find the eps file in /iraf/iraf/, rename it, move to proper output location, and delete the old eps file.
        iraf_dir = '/iraf/iraf/'
        eps_file_list = glob.glob(iraf_dir + 'sgi' + '*.eps')

        ...continuation of code

        if len(eps_file_list) == 1:
           eps_file_sub = os.path.basename(eps_file_list[0])

           cmd1 = 'cp {0} {1}'.format(eps_file_list[0], ccf_output_dir + object_name_sub + '.eps')
           cmd2 = 'rm {0}'.format(eps_file_list[0])
           cmd3 = 'sleep 0.05'
           process1 = subprocess.Popen("{}; {}; {}".format(cmd1, cmd2, cmd3), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
           process1.wait()
```

With process1 I'm sending three subprocess shell commands. The first is to copy the eps files from my /iraf directory to another directory (the iraf function which creates them in the first place does not allow me to give these files a proper name nor location for output). The second is to remove the eps file from my /iraf directory. The third command for forces the kernal to sleep. By doing this, Python does not receive a completed signal until the sleep command has been reached. This part I believe works perfectly. The only issue is that very rarely the iraf routine used to create the eps file doesn't create them fast enough when I reach this command.

```
        #endif

        num_cross = num_cross + 1
     #Endtry
     ...more code
```

This is a very clunky solution and not satisfy to the least bit but it does work 99.9% of the time. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know. This has been a very frustrating problem and everyone I've asked hasn't been able to come up with anything better (including people who program in python regularly in my astro department).